# Docker Compose with Two Spring Boot Application get "message": "I/O error on GET request for \"http://127.0.0.1:8010/....: Connection refused"

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have two small Spring Boot applications that exposes a rest API:

app-one

Get Request

```
 - http://localhost:8010/api/stock/AAPL
```

Response:

```
{
    "name": "AAPL",
    "value": 219.9
}
```

app-two

Get Request

```
 - http://localhost:8080/api/trade/APPL/buy/10
```

Response

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "stock": {
        "name": "APPL",
        "value": 219.9
    },
    "quantity": 10,
    "total": 2199.0
}
```

When I run this two apps on my localhost without Docker I get the correct response from both APIs.

When I run the apps using the Docker Compose, the first API app-one responds OK, but the app-two returns an error:

```
"message": "I/O error on GET request for \"http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/stock/APPL\": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)",
"path": "/api/trade/APPL/buy/10"
```

This is my docker-compose.yml configuration file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app-one:
    image: ibercode/app-one
    ports:
    - "8010:8010"
    expose:
      - "8010"
  app-two:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app-one      
    environment:
      - APP_ONE_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/stock/
```

And this is the output after I run the command `docker-compose up`

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting app-two_app-one_1 ... done
Starting app-two_app-two_1 ... done
Attaching to app-two_app-one_1, app-two_app-two_1
app-one_1  |
app-one_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
app-one_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
app-one_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
app-one_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
app-one_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
app-one_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
app-one_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)
app-one_1  |
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:07.287  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppOneApplication           : Starting AppOneApplication vlatest on a090eb18a661 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:07.291  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppOneApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
app-two_1  |
app-two_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
app-two_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
app-two_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
app-two_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
app-two_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
app-two_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
app-two_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)
app-two_1  |
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:08.308  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppTwoApplication           : Starting AppTwoApplication vlatest on 973897f9ea8d with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:08.325  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppTwoApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:10.448  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8010 (http)
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:10.536  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:10.537  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:10.731  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:10.744  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3313 ms
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.283  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.488  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.588  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.588  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.701  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8010 (http) with context path ''
app-one_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.705  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppOneApplication           : Started AppOneApplication in 5.488 seconds (JVM running for 6.129)
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.797  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:11.797  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3281 ms
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:12.077  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:12.249  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
app-two_1  | 2019-09-18 08:28:12.251  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ibercode.AppTwoApplication           : Started AppTwoApplication in 5.016 seconds (JVM running for 5.955)
```

Any idea or suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you are trying to access app-1 from app-2 with the URL http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/stock/APPL. However you can't access the other container under 127.0.0.1 from another container.

You can access another service in the compose file by service name. That means, you need to configure your app-2 application to look for the host `app-one`, i.e. `APP_ONE_URI=http://app-one/api/stock/`.

You can read more about Compose networking here https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.

Comment: So, the solution came from Mark, I had to declare in docker-compose.yml ...environment:
      - APP_ONE_URI=http://app-one:8010/api/stock/... and in the Spring App ...@Value("${APP_ONE_URI:http://localhost:8010/api/stock/}")
 private String url; ... Problem solved